# Java generics incompatible types conversion

Tags: java, generics

I'm facing yet another Java generics issue and need help on this one.

I have an entity class that should be able to carry an object of its own type :

```java
public abstract class BaseEntity<E extends BaseEntity<E>> {

    private E obj;

    [...]
}
```

There's also a Service class that will provide business logic on top of the entities and for which I need a callback :

```java
public abstract class BaseService<E extends BaseEntity<E>> {

    public void onPostUpdate(E entity) {

    }

    [...]
}
```

Now, the Hibernate listener class must be able to call the service class callback :

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EntityListenerImpl implements PostUpdateEventListener {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        [...]
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {
        BaseEntity<?> entity = (BaseEntity<?>) event.getEntity();
        final Class<?> serviceClass;
        try {
            serviceClass = Class.forName(entity.getClass().getName() + "Service");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        if( serviceClass.isAssignableFrom(BaseService.class) ) {
            BaseService<?> serviceBean = (BaseService<?>) applicationContext.getBean(serviceClass);
            serviceBean.onPostUpdate( entity );
        }
    }

    [...]
}
```

The listener is looking for the right service bean and executes the callback method with the entity attached. The whole code is not here (null checks have been stripped and so on). The mapping between entity classes and service classes should be done and stored in a map once and for all at init for efficiency. But this is not the point here.

When compiling, I can't find a way to avoid this kind of error :

```
EntityListenerImpl.java:26: error: incompatible types: BaseEntity<CAP#1> cannot be converted to CAP#2
            serviceBean.onPostUpdate( entity );
                                      ^
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends BaseEntity<CAP#1> from capture of ?
    CAP#2 extends BaseEntity<CAP#2> from capture of ?
```

I could change the callback signature so it takes an Object instead of a BaseEntity<?>, this would solve this issue. Yet I wonder if there's not something cleaner that could be done and could save the cast at runtime in the callback method.

Comment: The short answer is no.  Generics can’t work like this.  There is no safe way to make a class obtained by reflection parameterized.  In general, there is no safe way to do a mapping of `<X, SomeType<X>>` with different types for X.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply provide onPostUpdate in BaseService Service as below:

```
public void onPostUpdate(BaseEntity<?> entity) {
       
}
```

Moreover you are invoking onPostUpdate method on a wildcard serviceBean and not of a concrete type. Hence the compiler is shouting for it as the constructor takes the concrete type of BaseService class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the issue and was especially looking to challenge my design. I wish I could maybe find a better one and avoid runtime casting inside onPostUpdate(? entity).